# Compare named requirement expressed with C++20 concepts

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I am writing a sorting algorithm, that takes a comparison function, [similar to `std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort):

```
template <class RandomIt, class Compare>
void sort(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp);
```

It seems to me that the template parameter `Compare` perfectly matches the [`Compare` named requirement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare). I am trying to understand how to specify that constraint using C++ 20 concepts, such as `std::strict_weak_order` and `std::equivalence_relation`, but I am slightly confused.

If I quote [the article on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare),

> The type `T` satisfies *Compare* if
> The type `T` satisfies *BinaryPredicate*, and  Given
> comp, an object of type `T`
> `equiv(a, b)`, an expression equivalent to `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`

`std::strict_weak_ordering` could capture my constraints on `comp` in the description above, but what about `equiv`? `std::equivalence_relation` takes a relation as a first template parameter. What would it be in my sorting function?

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to use the `std::sortable` requirement that `std::ranges::sort` function uses?

Comment: @NicolBolas Urg, thanks. that's exactly what I was looking for. I was wondering why they were not using concepts on cppreferences for `std::sort`. They only used it in `std::ranges::sort`. I was also looking at the list here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/concepts. No mention of `std::sortable` there.

Comment: `std::sortable` is a requirement on `sort`, not on the comparator. The comparator should still satisfy `std::strict_weak_order` (or `std::indirect_strict_weak_order` as appropriate).

Comment: `equiv(a,b)` is defined to be the same as `!comp(a,b) && !comp(b,a)`, and *it* should satisfy `std::equivalence_relation`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, named requirements are wider in capabilities than concepts and constraints.

For example, I can have a named requirement that some algorithms halts.  On the other hand, there is no way to make a concept that requires an algorithm halts.

Concepts can check some things, but they cannot check everything.  So the named requirement Compare says first that the thing must be a BinaryPredicate. BinaryPredicate can be described as a concept and provided as a constraint.

Confirming

```
if comp(a,b)==true then comp(b,a)==false
```

would require either a proof subsystem of C++ to be added and the formal proof to be passed in alongside comp, or checking every single value of the types you pass to `comp`.

There are languages where you can pass around formal proofs of properties, and those formal proofs are checked to validate function arguments.  C++ is not one of them.

Rice's theorem states that you cannot take code and verify its non-trivial properties.  To pull off something similar to what you want, code would have to be augmented with proofs of what you claim about it.  This extra information could then be required by constraints.  Using the Turing tar pit, you could even augment C++ with this capability, but it wouldn't look much like C++ afterwards (and that is coming from me, who likes to add named operators to C++ for fun).

TL;DR not all named requirements can be expressed as concepts.  Concepts can check some things, but not everything.  Documenting additional requirements beyond what concepts constrain parameters is a thing in C++.